# Google Ads and Varnish

Tags: varnish

One of my website displays Google Ads to display in sidebar and header.

If I will install Varnish on that server will that ad also be cached ?
How to overcome this?

My TTL for varnish cache is 96days.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ads will not be cached, because Google ads are Javascript based. (the actual ads are pulled by Javascript code into your page dynamically, irrespective of Varnish cache).